# Can I pass a string from perl back to the calling c-shell?

Tags: perl, csh

RHEL6

I have a c-shell script that runs a perl script.  After dumping tons of stuff to stdout, it determines where (what dir) the parent shell should cd to when the perl script finishes.  But that's a string, not an int which is all I can pass back with "exit()".

Storing the name of the dir in a file which the c-shell script can read is what I have now.  It works, but is not elegant.  Is there a better way to do this ? Maybe a little chunk of memory that I can share with the perl script ?

Comment: Hmm, csh doesn't seem to have a way of opening additional file descriptors?

Comment: You should dump tons of stuff to a temporary file and return the string in STDOUT.

Comment: @shawnhcorey  My first recommendation as well, but then there is yet a bunch of other ways (which may be needed).  See my answer

Comment: "*I have a c-shell script*" - this is not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

**Short:**

- Redirect Perl's streams and restore in the end to print that info, taken by the shell script
- Or, print that *last* and the shell script can pass output to the console and take the last line
- Or, use a named pipe (either shell) or specific file descriptors (not `csh`) for that print

---

When the Perl script prints out that name you can assign it to a variable
in the shell script

```
#!/bin/csh
set DIR `perl -e'print "dir_name"'`
```

while in `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash    
DIR="$(perl -e'print "dir_name"')"
```

where `$(...)` is preferred for the command substitution.

But those other prints to console from the Perl script then need be handled

- One way is to redirect all output in Perl script other than that one print, what can be controlled by a command-line option (filename to which to redirect, which shell script can print out)
- Or, take all Perl's output and pass it to console, the last line being the needed "return."  This puts the burden on the Perl script to print that last (perhaps in an `END` block). The program's output can be printed from the shell script after it completes or line by line as it is emitted.
- Or, use a *named pipe* (both shells) or a specific file descriptor (`bash` only) to which the Perl script can print that information.  In this case its streams go straight to the console.

The question explicitly mentions `csh` so it is given below. But I must repeat the old and worn fact that shell scripting is far better done in `bash` than in `csh`. I strongly recommend to reconsider.

#### bash

If you need the program's output on the console as it goes, take and print it line by line

```
#!/bin/bash    
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
    DIR=$line
done < <(perl script.pl)
echo "$DIR"
```

Or, if you don't need output on the console before the script is finished

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t lines < <(perl script.pl)
DIR="${lines[-1]}"
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}"           # print script.pl's output
```

Or, use file descriptors for that particular print

```
F=$(mktemp)    # safe filename
exec 3> "$F"   # open fd 3 to write to it
exec 4< "$F"   # open fd 4 to read from it
rm -f "$F"     # remove file(name) for safety; opened fd's can still access
perl -E'$fd=shift; say "...normal prints to STDOUT..."; 
    open(FH, ">&=$fd") or die $!; 
    say FH "dirname"; 
    close FH
' 3
read dir_name <&4
exec 3>&-          # close them
exec 4<&-
echo "$dir_name"
```

I couldn't get it to work with a single file descriptor for both reading and writing (`exec 3<> ...`), I think because the read can't rewind after the write, thus separate descriptors are used.

With a Perl script (and not the demo one-liner above) pass the fd number as a command-line option. The script can then do this only if it's invoked with that option.

Or, use a named pipe very similarly to how it's done for `csh` below.  This is probably best here, if the manipulation of the program's `STDOUT` isn't to your liking.

#### csh

Iterate over the program's (completed) output line by line

```
#!/bin/csh
foreach line ( "`perl script.pl`" )
    echo "$line"
    set dir_name = "$line"
end
echo "Directory name: $dir_name"
```

or extract the last line first and then print the whole output

```
#!/bin/csh
set lines = ( "`perl script.pl`" )
set dir_name = $lines[$#]
# Print program's output
while ( $#lines )
     echo "$lines[1]"
     shift lines
 end
```

or use a *named pipe*

```
set fifo_name = "/tmp/fifo$$"  # or use mktemp
mkfifo "$fifo_name"
( perl script.pl --fifo $fifo_name [other args]  & )
set dir_name = `cat "$fifo_name"`
rm -f $fifo_name

echo "dir name from FIFO: $dir_name"
```

The Perl command is in the background since FIFO blocks until written *and* read. So if the shell script were to wait for `perl ...` to complete the Perl script would block as it's writing to FIFO (since that's not being read) so shell would never get to read it; we would deadlock. It is also in a subshell, with `( )`, so to avoid the informational prints about the background job.

The `--fifo NAME` command-line option is needed so that Perl script knows what special file to use (and not to do this if the option is not there).

For an in-line example replace `( perl script ...)` with this one-liner, used above as well

```
( perl -E'$ff = shift; say qq(\t...normal prints to STDOUT...); 
     open FF, ">$ff" or die $!; 
     say FF "dir_name_$$"; 
     close FF
 ' $fifo_name 
& )
```

(broken over lines for readability)

Comment: The OP is using csh, not bash.

Comment: Would it be possible to capture a channel diffeent to stdout? So that the program has only to output the ''dir_name'' into that channel but all other output will be passed through?

Comment: Any thoughts on using /dev/shm for this ?

Comment: @daveg I don't think that one should poke around there just so, and it would be far more complicated  (if possible), in every sense, than any of what I showed. Solutions with other file descriptors use the filesystem, which you didn't like I thought. (I'll try, perhaps it won't be as bad ..)

Comment: @aschepler Thank you again, completed

Comment: @daveg  Added: using a named pipe (both shells) and using specific file descriptors (`bash` only)